# Interpreting Wireshark output for a ping test between two machines

Tags: networking, ping, wireshark

***Full disclosure***: I am a student, and yes, I am working on a [lab report](http://www.cis.syr.edu/~wedu/seed/Labs_16.04/Networking/Sniffing_Spoofing/) for my Internet Security course, but this is not a direct lab question- I'm just curious to understand more about the outputs I'm seeing.

I have set up two virtual machines using Professor Kevin Du's [SEED lab VMs](http://www.cis.syr.edu/~wedu/Teaching/InternetSecurity/labs.html). I set up two Ubuntu machines on Machine A `10.0.2.4` and Machine B `10.0.2.5`. I then try pinging `10.0.2.7` from Machine A. I get the following output:

[image]

On Wireshark, I notice that ARP packets are being sent asking for the MAC address of `10.0.2.7`. I understand that this is because Machine A does not know the MAC address of `10.0.2.7` when it attempts to ping that particular IP (and it receives a `Destination not reachable` because no machine responds to that particular ARP request.

[image]

This implies that no packets destined for `10.0.2.7` were ever sent. However, I wrote a small sniffer program on Machine B (`10.0.2.5`) using `pcap` for packets with destination IP `10.0.2.7`, and I do indeed sniff packets headed that way:

[image]

However, my two questions here are:

1. What is `PcsCompu_88:8c:cc`? Is that the MAC address of my machine at `10.0.2.4`? If it is, why is that displayed instead of Machine A's IP address `10.0.2.4`? When does Wireshark choose to display the MAC address versus the IP address?
2. Why is there still packet traffic sniffed by Machine B headed towards `10.0.2.7`? All I can see in Wireshark from Machine B are ARP broadcasts asking for the MAC address of `10.0.2.7`.

Comment: You might have more success asking this on different site on the [StackExchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites#), e.g. [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) or [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MAC address is 6 bytes comprised of 3 bytes manufacturer and 3 byte for the unique device part.  PcsCompu is what manufacturer bytes get looked up as.  88:8c:cc is the second three bytes.

ARP packets operate at layer 2 because they are used when the information for layer 3 (IP) communication isn't available yet.  WireShark will display all header fields of a packet.  If it was an IP packet it would display source IP address.

The only packets on the network would be the ARPs which are broadcast to all hosts on the subnet would receive them.